# What is the best way to send a message to all my users' devices at once?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app in the Android market, and I have over 50 thousands users. I need to send a message to all my users at a certain time. What is the best way to send a message to all my users' devices at once?

I was reading about Android GCM. GCM requires each app to be registered and have a unique id. It also says that I can only send a message to a limited number of devices (1000). I couldn't understand if it meant a 1000 devices at once or what? And I really don't need the IDs, because I'm sending the same message to all my users.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The 1000 limit applies when you send the same message to multiple devices - you are allowed to specify up to 1000 registration IDs in the JSON request.

If you want to send the same message to more than a 1000 users, you'll have to split them into groups of 1000 registration IDs and send to each group in a separate request to the GCM server.

GCM requires that you specify the registration IDs of all devices that should receive the notification. There is no way to broadcast a message to all users without specifying their registration IDs.

Comment: Would you use GCM to send a message to all users? Or Is there any other way?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I would. I'm not familiar with other ways.